# Creating URL from form fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So, i'm really new to HTML and javascript, and I want to take values from a form and process them with a script.  I have a couple of fields including username, password, and two confirm password fields in HTML.  With javascript I want to collect the username, and check if the password field is filled out.  If it is, I want to make var ispass equal to 'yespass' or 'nopass'.  When I submit the form, I want to go the url http://www.example.com?un=username&pass=yespass (or nopass).

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function processFormData(){
        var user = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
        var ispass;
          if (pass.length > 0){
          ispass = "yespass";
          }else{
          ispass = "nopass";
          }
        return "http://www.example.com?un=" + user + "&pw=" + ispass;
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="window.location.href=processFormData();">
Please enter your current e-mail address and password below.<br><br>
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="E-mail Address"><br><br>
<input type="password" id="oldpassword" placeholder="Old Password"><br><br><br>
Please type your new password below:<br><br>
<input type="password" id="newpassword1" placeholder="New Password"><br><br>
<input type="password" id="newpassword2" placeholder="Confirm New Password"><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="gobutton" value="Reset Password"/>
</form>
```

I cannot figure out a proper way to do this, because this does not seem to be working at all.  Any suggestions or recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You could pull this off with a hidden form field and an onchange event:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ispass" value="no" onchange="checkPass(this);" />
```

This input would go in your form. Then on your password field, add an `onchange` handler:

```
function checkPass(input) {
    document.getElementById("ispass").value =  "yes"
};
```

Also, if you set the `method` on your form, submitting the form can generate the url based on the form inputs:

```
<form method='get' action='...' />
```

[Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates the result](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronfay/7usj1r02/1/).

Also, if you're new to javascript, you may want to look into a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to simplify some of your interaction with the page. It's really easy to learn, and there's a great community around it to help with any problems you might run into.

HTH,
Aaron

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer.  Also, I had no idea jsfiddle existed, and I was looking for this exact thing earlier.  Thanks!!  Anywho, if I use the method GET, wouldnt it generate the URL with all of the form values (including the password and "new password")?

Comment: It would also send `password`, yes. If you don't want to submit the form and just make an ajax request, you can just build up the url with the values from the form you want just like in your original example.